# MVC Login form fails with KendoUI

Tags: kendo-ui

I created a new MVC 4  application then selected 'Configure Project' from the Telerik menu. No other modifications were made.

When I run the application and click on the [login] option, the application errors with the message:

---

Unhandled exception at line 115, column 5 in http://localhostthatitwontletmeput.co.uk:49591/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js

0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'live'

---

The application breaks at the line below.

```
$("a[data-ajax=true]").live("click", function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    asyncRequest(this, {
        url: this.href,
        type: "GET",
        data: []
    });
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: That looks a bit like a jquery selector/function and `live` is deprecated with jquery.

Comment: Interesting, I just downloaded the KendoUI stuff to trial, created a vanilla application and it doesn't work, seems strange that such basic functionality wouldn't be tested, surely there are a lot of people using this?